How do I get the current CPU temp in asm?
I'm trying to write a program where I need to read the current CPU temp. Due to the nature of the environment im working in, this needs to be done in assembly. For some background information im using an intel processor.
I've looked online and haven't found any help on the subject.

The answer's going to depend quite heavily on the exact environment you're in. If you're on an RTOS making some kind of embedded device that monitors its own temperature, your best bet is probably to just stick a temperature probe to your chip and hook it up via GPIO or whatever. If you're on Linux and can install software before running your program, you're probably better off just writing some code that reads from the same device files as lm-sensors, so reading that project's source code would be your best bet. Can you edit your question to clarify?

Intel x86 CPUs have MSRs you can read (in kernel mode only, of course).  The linked duplicate talks about this and says which Intel manual has more details.  I'm assuming any context where assembly is the only option is also one where you're running in supervisor mode (ring 0) or real mode, so can use privileged instructions like rdmsr.  If not, you need to specify more details of the environment.

What operating system are you programming for, if any?
